# Find child classes and group them on parent div

Tags: php, jquery

I want to find all child classes with their id in each mother div that is listed per web page.
With that, the id's of the child div's should be grouped by the mainID - to use with an ajax post.

However, I don't even get the child's id's in jquery 1.11, let alone to group them with the mainID.

This is the code so far:

```
$(".main-column-name").each(function() {
    var mainID = $(this).attr('id');

    var subid = $(this).find(".subdiv-name").attr("id");
    alert(mainID + ' ' + subid );
});
```

So, under the mainID should be a group of subID's - if they exist of course.

Any help is welcome!!!

Comment: Do you know what `closest` exactly does?

Comment: sorry, i tried all variations and left this one. Children etc. doesn't show anything, so I am kind of lost. That's when I ask it here.

Comment: It selects the closest matching parent element which doesn't seem to be what you want. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/). There are all the jQuery's traversing methods. You are probably looking for the `find` method.

Comment: Thanks man! I am there now. But how do I group all those found in preferably an array named as the mainID and then throw it into an ajax datastring?

Answer (score 0):

You can write it to an object array and attach the children as a sub-array to this.

```
var mainEl = $(".main-column-name")
    mainArr = [],
    childArr = [];

//set the properties in an array to be used later
mainEl.each(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id')
        children = $(this).find('.subdiv-name').attr('id');

    children.each(function() {
        //add the child IDs to an array
        childArr.push($(this).attr('id'))
    });

    //push all the properties into an array
    mainArr.push({ 'name': id, 'children': childArr });

});


//to access the properties, use a loop
$.each(mainArr, function (i, value) {

    //get the name
    console.log(mainArr[i].name);

    //get the children
    console.log(mainArr[i].children);

    //and to access the child IDs individually, use this loop within the loop
    $.each(mainArr[i].children, function(c, id) {

        //get the stored value for id
        console.log(id)
    });
});
```

Use this carefully though, as running a loop within a loop might cause you some performance issues if there will be lots of children and lots of parents. Someone else might be able to advise on a better way of extracting this information other than this... I will update if I think of a better method myself, but I haven't had too much time to look at it.